# MotionLayout resets views when transition starts

Tags: android, android-animation, android-constraintlayout, android-jetpack, android-motionlayout

I am using constraint layout 2.0.0-alpha3,
i have added an animation on swipe event

```
    <Transition
        android:id="@+id/profile_transition"
        app:constraintSetEnd="@+id/ending_set"
        app:constraintSetStart="@+id/starting_set"
        app:duration="1000">

    <OnSwipe
            app:dragDirection="dragUp"
            app:touchAnchorId="@+id/ivBackground"
            app:touchAnchorSide="top"/>

</Transition>
```

constraint sets are containing the constraints of the views that are taking part in this animation, 
so problem following: if i want to change other views programmatically, when transition starts on swipe event, they are being reset(eg: visibility)

Comment: I added this post to https://issuetracker.google.com/123015418